# Media image file Blocked and permission denied in nougat

Tags: android, image, camera, capture, mediastore

I have got the error while replacing the capture image with converted bitmap to image.

```
Intent intent =new Intent(this,Myclass.class);
intent.setData(params[0]);
sendBroadcast(intent);
```

in Broadcast class

```
Uri uri=intent.getData();
```

Copy Method

```
private File CopyImage(String sourcepath, String targetpath) {
        File sourceLocation = new File(sourcepath);
        File targetLocation = new File(targetpath);
        InputStream in = null;
        OutputStream out = null;
        try {
            in = new FileInputStream(sourceLocation);
            out = new FileOutputStream(targetLocation);
            // Copy the bits from instream to outstream
            byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
            int len;
            while ((len = in.read(buf)) > 0) {
                out.write(buf, 0, len);
            }
            in.close();
            out.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return targetLocation;
    }
```

When I am accessing the targetpath

```
content://media/external/images/media/19392?blocking=1&orig_id=19392&group_id=0
```

Permission granted

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Comment: `Bitmap Image = Uri.getData();` will not compile, as [`Uri` does not have a `getData()` method](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/Uri.html). So, please provide a [mcve], with the complete Java stack trace associated with your error and the *actual* code that generated that stack trace.

Comment: Update Code and method generating error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When I am accessing the targetpath

That is not a path. That is the string representation of a `Uri`. And a `Uri` is not a file.

So:

- Replace `String targetpath` with `Uri target`
- Get rid of `File targetLocation = new File(targetpath);`
- Pass a `ContentResolver` into the method, which you get by calling `getContentResolver()` on a `Context`
- Replace `out = new FileOutputStream(targetLocation);` with `out = cr.openOutputStream(target);` where `cr` is your `ContentResolver`

Comment: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.SecurityException: External path: /storage/7832-E808/DCIM/Camera/20170701_113307.jpg: Neither user 10326 nor current process has android.permission.WRITE_MEDIA_STORAGE.

Comment: I am able to write image on SD card but I m facing image rotate issues in Samsung device, can u help me out plz

Answer (score 0):

Are you assigned run time permission like below,

```
private int REQUEST_READ_PERMISSION=1;
 private boolean checkAndRequestPermissions() {

        int externalStoragePermission = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);

        List<String> listPermissionsNeeded = new ArrayList<>();


        if (externalStoragePermission != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            listPermissionsNeeded.add(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
        }
        if (!listPermissionsNeeded.isEmpty()) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(mActivity, listPermissionsNeeded.toArray(new String[listPermissionsNeeded.size()]), REQUEST_READ_PERMISSION);

            return false;
        }
        return true;

    }

@Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        if(REQUEST_READ_PERMISSION ==requestCode)
        {

        }
    }
```

Comment: getting approved of permission  by ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(getActivity(), listPermissionsNeeded.toArray(new String[listPermissionsNeeded.size()]), STORAGE_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE);

Comment: yes it work fine in marshmallow facing issue with nougat